# Joining a recordset and table in MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to join a table with a recordset through VBA.  Is this possible?  I basically wanted to join two tables, but one of the tables needed to be filtered down even more before I joined them.

Comment: You can typically use UNION to join two recordsets (assuming you mean append and not merge)  If that's not what you want then a few more details might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want:

```
SELECT ID, field1, field2 
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, field3, field4
    FROM Table2
    WHERE field5 = 42 ) b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a join on a recordset, as far as I know. And even if it is possible, it will require code that is way too convoluted to be useful.)

I suggest that instead of using the **recordset** in the join, make a temporary **table** from the recordset.

Alternatively, use the query you used to make the recordset to just make a temporary table directly. Then use an SQL query to join the first table with the temporary table.
Say you have in your database a table **table1** and **tableA**;

```
dim sqlString1 As String
dim sqlString2 As String
'the temporary table - this is what was in your recordset 
sqlString1 = "SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 INTO tempTable"
'the join of existing tableA with the tempTable
sqlString2 = "SELECT field1, field2, fieldA, fieldB INTO joinedTable"& _
             "FROM table1"& _
             "JOIN tableA ON field1 = fieldA" 
CurrentDB.Execute sqlString1
CurrentDB.Execute sqlString2
```

Notice that I put the `JOIN` results in another table in the database. Alternatively, you can save the results in a recordset.

Comment: What exactly are table1, tableA, joinedTable and tempTable?  I'm having difficulty understanding which is which in the example.

Comment: I ended up finding clarity [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-inner-joins.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with making a temp table. Also, depending on the size of your local table, you could create a string of values to pass to your SQL server query. (SELECT __ FROM __ WHERE ___ IN ( string of values). Tricky, but might be useful if your local table is small and the join significantly reduces your SQL query results.

For my situation, the local table did not reduce my server query results. So I just did an update with my local table.